# Android JNI calculate not correct

Tags: android, java-native-interface

My question is about using jni in android platform.

I have a simple for loop logic as follows:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_test_video_Test_test(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj){ 

    jint i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 1024; i++){
        LOGI("index=%d", i);
    }
}
```

the output is not ok:

```
index=688
index=689
index=690
index=691
index=692
index=800
index=807
index=808
```

Briefly speaking, the results of the console output are not continuous, as expected.

Can you help me fix this issue?

Comment: Do the missing numbers appear in another position? (Is just the order messed up or are they completely missing?)

Comment: Perhaps some of the logs were dropped because you tried to output too many logs in too short a time period. Do you have a real-world example where this caused a problem?

Comment: ok , now I try to check the log hint.

Comment: Try to use: __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "TheTag", "Value - %d", i); fflush(stdout); This way, you will be able to check whether your logs are stuck in the buffer or whether this is something related to console. Note that it might be issue of the IDE itself. E.g. console line number limits, etc. You can always double check whether everything is OK by setting breakpoint at line LOGI("index=%d", i); and counting it. I bet this issue is related to IDE, not to your code.